# Floating action button Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton When using in DrawerLayout

Tags: xml, android-fragments, inflate-exception, floating-action-button

I am currently using a DrawerLayout as my root layout to access the sliding menu that contain my fragments. I want to add a FAB across all fragments but get the error -

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML
>   file line #21: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

I have tried to contain it within a FrameLayout but still get the same error. I have also tried multiple images as I am aware this error can occur when the image has more pixels than there is memory for the application. My target SDK is 23 and I have compiled the relevant appcompat libraries as such.

Some extra info;

Main Activity XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.liamk.version2.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_list_black_24dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigationheader">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.liamk.version2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev225-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

Theme

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to this that I forgot to post.

Use a Tab Layout as the child in a parent Coordinator Layout. Material design is your friend.